# Locking on static object

Tags: java, multithreading

There are multiple instance of Class A that runs at a time.

Class A calls multiple instances of Class B in its run.

```
public Class Main {

    public static void main(String args[] ) {

        A a1 = new A();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(a1);
        t1.start();

        A a2 = new A();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(a2);
        t2.start();
    }
}

Class A implements Runnable {

    public void run() {

        B b1 = new B();
        Thread t11 = new Thread(b1);
        t11.start();

        B b2 = new B();
        Thread t21 = new Thread(b2);
        t21.start();
    }
}
```

There is method named "method" in class B where a Set Collection is edited. That edit is done based on static lock in Class B.

## **EDIT**-

```
Class B implements Runnable {

    private final static Object LOCK = new Object();
    private final static Set<T> busyRecords = new HashSet<T>();

    public void waitToWorkOn(final T obj) {
        synchronized(LOCK) {
            while (busyRecords.contains(obj)) {
        LOCK.wait(); //go to sleep
       }
       busyRecords.add(obj);            
    }
    }

    public void doneWith(final T obj) {
        synchronized(LOCK) {
           busyRecords.remove(obj);
      LOCK.notifyAll(); 
    }
    }

    public void mathod(obj)  {

     try{
        waitToWorkOn(obj);

         .. do some work with obj
     }
     finally {
        doneWith(obj);
     }
    }

    public void run() {
        method(getObj())
    }
}
```

*But that Set does **not** need concurrency control when it is accessed from different "A" instances. Only within an A instance, it needs to be locked for all B instances*.

**By this I mean, that when 2 instances of A are running, they should not be made to wait. But within an A instance if 2 B objects pick same obj, they have to wait inside LOCK.wait.**

I don't think that LOCK can be made non-static as A calls multiple instances of B.Can we tune LOCK object here  for better concurrency across A objects.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: `There is method named "method" in class C where a Set Collection is edited. That edit is done based on static lock in Class C.`.. Where is C class defined in your code?

Comment: move LOCK and someSet to A as instance members?

Comment: Right now LOCK object locks t1 and t2 both as it is static. I need to lock only t1 here from class MAin

Comment: @Vishal - corrected I am only thinking if I can run two A instances without blocking each other. THere is still need for concurrency inside A  .. BTW, that set is only a way how I keep track of busy records and there is a complimentary wait and notify in my code to not let 2 threads work on same object at a time.

Comment: @irreputable - I think I can not do that as you can consider that Set doig work something like ConcurrentLinkedQueue for increasing concurrency in Class B and locking at same time

Comment: `someSet` is class variable of class `B`. And this set will be used by all the objects of `B` created in your program, So your LOCK can't be non-static in your code. But it wont lead to concurrency issue while you reading the element from set, You can define a method within `B` to read the set without creating any LOCK on it..Although it won't guarantee that you will be getting latest updated set while reading the set values.

Comment: @Vishal , I have myself added static to that lock Object and idea was to lock access to B objects for given A object. But this unnecessarily locks all A instances as well. And here I need to do "new" for creating THreads as each A / B instances are basically reusable GenericObjectPool objects

Comment: Even if you create the LOCK for each object of `A` instead of for all objects of `B` do'nt you think that it will lead to unsychronized updation of `busyRecords` of class `B` since it will be shared by all objects of `B` and hence all objects of `A` as it is static.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a thread-safe instance of the shared collection and pass it to all the Bs for a given A.

```
Class A implements Runnable {

    public void run() {

        // create shared set instance scoped to A, and make it thread-safe
        Set col = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet());

        B b1 = new B(col);
        Thread t11 = new Thread(b1);
        t11.start();

        B b2 = new B(col);
        Thread t21 = new Thread(b2);
        t21.start();
    }
}

Class B implements Runnable {

    private final Set<T> someSet;

    private B(Set<T> someSet) {
      this.someSet = someSet;
    }

    public void method(final T obj) {
        someSet.add(obj);
    }

    public void run() {
        method()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can i instead just move my LOCK object inside A -> run() and pass that object to B . In B, I have a bunch of SETS for controlling a inserts into lot of tables.. In this way I continue to use my code , only LOCK object wil be not static object but a scoped A objct

Comment: @fortm - sure, that works as well (basically the same solution as mine, just different lock instance).  better yet would be to encapsulate this shared B state into a new class and just synchronize its methods.